# Unable to access keyvault from Azure DevOps from a different resource description

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to build out my DevOps pipeline to deploy a DataFactory, Databricks Notebooks & Azure Data Warehouse,

I have my resource subscriptions setup for both Dev and Prod. deploying to Prod is more tricky than it seems.

my keyvault has GET/LIST Permissions for both Secret & Keys for the Target DataFactory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

I have used the above guide to setup my target data factory in prod - and it is stood up correctly with all the connection strings setup and keyvault permissions set.

but I am stuck on this portion :

> Grant permissions to the Azure Pipelines agent The Azure Key Vault
>   task may fail with an Access Denied error if the proper permissions
>   aren't present. Download the logs for the release, and locate the .ps1
>   file with the command to give permissions to the Azure Pipelines
>   agent. You can run the command directly, or you can copy the principal
>   ID from the file and add the access policy manually in the Azure
>   portal. Get and List are the minimum permissions required.

when I deploy my release I get the following error on the KeyVault task :

> The specified Azure service connection needs to have Get, List secret management permissions on the selected key vault. To set these permissions, download the ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1 script from build/release logs and execute it, or set them from the Azure portal

I've added this power shell script `ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1` to my repo and added it to my task but it just runs forever ? unsure if I'm missing something here.

hope this is clear/ please ask for any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's the DevOps service connection that's missing the permissions.
You can check access policies for the vault from the console.  You should see your service connection as an APPLICATION; it needs the GET and LIST privileges as the document your following says.  My understanding is that these are privileges for the account that's deploying your code, rather than the account that will run your code.

[image]

Comment: stupid question, but by Service Connection do you mean the name of my DevOps pipeline? in regards to my own DF I've set these permissions before hand so i don't think it is that?

Comment: Hi.  By Service Connection I mean the connection you would have set up from DevOps (you can see Service Connections from the Project Settings in DecOps).  This creates an Enterprise Application and Service Principal with Azure AD so that DevOps can deploy to your subscription.  It's not the same as the permissions for Data Factory (which is what I'm assuming DF means).

Answer (score 0):

I converted the `ProvisionKeyVaultPermissions.ps1` script (using RM) provided to AZ.  My shell complained about the old modules.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

# Install and import the Az.KeyVault module
Install-Module -Name Az.KeyVault
Import-Module -Name Az.KeyVault

# Login to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId '...'

# Get the service principal
$spn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId '...'
$spnObjectId = $spn.Id

# Set the key vault access policy
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName '...' -ObjectId $spnObjectId -PermissionsToSecrets get,list
```